# React maskImage inline not working - same image works as backgroundImage

Tags: css, reactjs, mask

I am applying inline style to a div in React

If I do

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.IMAGES}/${ID}.png)` }}>{children}</div>
```

it works fine, but on changing to

```
<div style={{ maskImage: `url(${process.env.IMAGES}/${ID}.png)` }}>{children}</div>
```

the style doesn't even show in the code inspector.

What could be wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the mask needs vendor prefixes to work, you'll need to add them manually:

```js
const Mask = ({ mask, children }) => (
  <div style={{
    WebkitMaskImage: mask,
    maskImage: mask
  }}>
    {children}
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Mask mask="linear-gradient(black, transparent)">The big bad fox</Mask>,
  root
)
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```